# Getting error while importing angular material style

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, angular-cli, node-sass

I tried to follow below link to install and use material text field
https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/text-field/

step one was to install it using below command
***install @material/textfield***

step second was to import its styling wherever we want to use this component
***@import "@material/textfield/mdc-text-field";***

When I write above line in my app.component.scss, it gives me below error
***File to import not found or unreadable: @material/textfield/mdc-text-field.

      in D:\Learning\Angular\test3\src\app\app.component.scss (line 1, column 1)***

When I tried to put **~** in front of import url, It found *mdc-text-field*, but than I got another error as
***File to import not found or unreadable: @material/floating-label/mdc-floating-label.

      in D:\Learning\Angular\test3\node_modules@material\textfield\mdc-text-field.scss (line 24, column 1)***

So seems now I need to put **~** operator in every import statement inside all scss file which are being used by *mdc-text-field.scss*

Isn't it an overhead putting **~** everywhere?

My project structure is like this

```
>node_modules
>src
    >app
        >app module folder consisting (app.component.scss etc)
    >assets
```

Comment: `https://material.angular.io/` follow this link for material

Comment: @Abhishek So you mean, I don't need to install these individual material elements, I can directly import them in app and use as components?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: cool, thanks man.
lemme try

Comment: its pleasure to help you